# Which traffic is able to update the ARP cache?

Tags: cisco, arp

Am I correct that only *ARP request* and *ARP reply* messages will update the Cisco IOS ARP cache?

Comment: Please tell us what system or platform you're asking about...

Comment: @Mike Pennington Devices with BSD or Linux kernel. Also devices running IOS.

Comment: Please ask on [sf] for bsd or Linux questions. Cisco IOS is on-topic

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that ARP Requests / Replys are the *only* way an address makes it into the FIB, but it is certainly the most predominant. [Gratutious ARP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7716/3191) has been mentioned a few times, and with good reason. It doesn't follow the standard ARP Request/Reply procedures, but certainly accomplishes the same goal – populating the FIB with a relevant entry.

Don’t forget about manual intervention.  Another way of populating the FIB is by manually setting a static address on the interface or having one automatically stick with port-security.

Answer (score -4):

In general — yeah. There's special case of ARP messages called Gratuitous ARP, but anyways there're either replies or requests.

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/16335
http://wiki.wireshark.org/Gratuitous_ARP

Comment: Hi, that answer is a bit unspecific and you're only referencing links. Could you perhaps elaborate more so that the question has a meaningful answer?

Comment: no, there's no sense to copy-paste docs. Answer it yourself.

Comment: @poige, SE prefers to not have answers that get the main content from links.  The reason for this is that link dependent answers are subject to "link rot" and can result in answers that are no longer be useful to the community.

Comment: I hear this crap from time to time, but it's just crap. Do you really want to build your own internet (with blackjack and sluts) instead, which wouldn't rot? ;-P

The whole idea behind Internet is hypertext, not copy-paste text.

Comment: @poige, perhaps you hear this from time to time because there is room to improve your answers.  Please read [shog9's question in meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/160519)

Comment: Or perhaps it's a crap and you can't understand why it is crap.